# How do I include indicator images with <div> show/hide code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to hide and show `div`s:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.hide').click(function() { 
        $(this).closest('.hideable').find('.hide-container').toggle();
    });

    $('a#hide-all').click(function() {
        $('.hide-container').hide(); });
    $('.hide-container').hide();
});
```

I have a problem: how can I add images such as a `+` mark when the `div` is hidden and a `-` mark when it is shown?

Comment: I notice you [asked this same question earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074685/add-image-to-show-hide-div-javascript).  Please don't post duplicate questions.  I'm moving my answer to that post.

Answer (score 1):

Set the image as a background in your css:

```
.hideable {
    background-image: url(minus.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 1px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
.hidden {
    background-image: url(plus.png);
}
.hidden .hide-container {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of `.toggle()`.  Apply the class to the parent element:

```
$('a.hide').click(function() { 
    $(this).closest('.hideable').toggleClass("hidden");
});
$('a#hide-all').click(function() {
    $('.hideable').addClass("hidden");
});
$('.hideable').addClass("hidden");
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/rK7yN/

**Edit:** If you want the images to be clickable:

```
.hideable a.hide {
    background-image: url(minus.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 1px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
.hidden a.hide {
    background-image: url(plus.png);
}
.hidden .hide-container {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/rK7yN/1/

Answer (score 0):

While reformating your code it came out with this:

```
$('a.hide').click(function() { 
   $(this).closest('.hideable').find('.hide-container').toggle(); 
});
$('a#hide-all').click(function() {
   $('.hide-container').hide();
});
$('.hide-container').hide();

}); // <-- What is this?
```

Maybe that is why it is not working?