# How to add image to show/hide div javascript?

Tags: javascript

Any suggestions how to add image (like + or - ) to show/hide div in javascript?

I'm using this code to show/hide divs:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.hide').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.hideable').find('.hide-container').toggle();
    });
    $('a#hide-all').click(function() {
        $('.hide-container').hide();
    });
    $('.hide-container').hide();
    $('a.hide').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

How can I add indicator images?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question fully, please explain with a little more details. On the other hand, you can use CSS display:hidden property to hide any HTML tag.

Comment: ok, I'm need add +-image while div is hidden and when user presses link it will show content. While link is pressed image should change as minus image. So i was wondering is it possible add those images to that javascript code?

Comment: I am sorry I honestly cannot understand what are you trying to achieve. Perhaps somebody else can help.

Answer (score 0):

this is just pseudo code:

> ```
> $(image).click(function(){
>    $(div).toggle('fast',function(){
>       if($(div).is(":visible"))$(image).attr('src','minus-image');
>       else $(image).attr('src','plus-image');
>    });
> });
> ```

Comment: Think I'm doing something wrong.. I added those rows but nothing seems to happen..

Comment: did you change it to your code? you know it's just pseudo code, right?

Comment: i change divs names but not sure how to what to add $(image) ??

Comment: that's the selector of the image you want to click on.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as a background in your css:

```
.hideable a.hide {
    background-image: url(minus.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
.hidden a.hide {
    background-image: url(plus.png);
}
.hidden .hide-container {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of `.toggle()`.  Apply the class to the parent element:

```
$('a.hide').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.hideable').toggleClass("hidden");
});
$('a#hide-all').click(function() {
    $('.hideable').addClass("hidden");
});
$('.hideable').addClass("hidden");
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/rK7yN/1/